# Advanced JQuery Form Submitting

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm familiar with Malsup ajaxForm plugin. I think it could be improved, but I'm not sure how to tweak it, so I'd like to just write my own.

I have a forms in this exact format:

```
<form id="form1" action="./file.php" method="post" class="ajaxform">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="updateValues" />
<fieldset><legend>Form Descriptor</legend>
<input ... />
<input ... />
<input ... />
<input type="submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I'd like to write a simple form ajaxer that submits the data, and can be initiated similar to malsup's

```
$('.ajaxform').ajaxify(); // or
$('.ajaxform').each(function(id, o) { ... });
```

but whatever contents are returned - the contents inside the `<fieldset>` are updated.
similar to

```
$('#form1 fieldset').load('file.php #form1 fieldset')
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's undocumented that the function callback passed to malsup's `ajaxForm()` actually receives parameters.

```
$('.ajaxform').each(function(id, o) {
        $(o).ajaxForm(function(data){
                $(o).html(data); // or whatever it is you want to do
        })
});
```